# Unable to pass data from ViewControllerClass to TableViewControllerClass

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

i want to pass textField data from my UIViewController Class to a UITableViewController Class with the method - 
which is from a button (IBAction) function 
[image: image description here]

but its not working, gives an error ---

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard () doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'attention'' //and so on

i have all stuff properly initialized.. 
This is my code for ViewController class ->

```
class CredentialViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var idTextField: UITextField!

    @IBAction func credit(sender: AnyObject) {

    if idTextField.text?.isEmpty != true {
        let attendance = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("attention") as! attendenceTableViewController
        attendance.creden = Int(idTextField.text!)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(attendance, animated: true)
    }
    else {
        print("Empty")
    }
}
```

And code for TableViewController is --->

```
class attendenceTableViewController: UITableViewController {
var checkins = [attendance]()
var creden:Int?

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    jsonParsingFromFile()
}
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    print(creden)
}
```

Comment: Have you got more than one storyboard?

Comment: show us `self.storyboard`

Comment: yes i have 6 storyboards

Comment: Check your storyboard object

Comment: and one more thing, start class names with big letter :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using different storyboards for this view, don't use

```
self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier
```

use

```
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
var viewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("attention") as! attendenceTableViewController
```

or whatever storyboard you use

Comment: due to this i lost my TabBarControls when i switch to tableViewController

Comment: try to make less storyboards, they are there to let you connect views easier you should use that. If you move that viewcontroller there, you will be able to make segue and keep tab bar. Or add new tabbar here

Answer (score -1):

As your ViewController is not in Main.StoryBoard so you would have to change your line where you are creating the new controller like this

```
let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "YourStoryBoardName", bundle:nil)
let attendance = storyBoard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("attention") as! attendenceTableViewController
attendance.creden = Int(idTextField.text!)
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(attendance, animated: true)
```

> **NOTE:** YourStoryBoardName would be your StoryBoard Name